# How to convert object to array of objects javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following object data which looks like this:

```
data = {
          anna:{
                 phase1:23,
                 phase2:24,
                 phase3:0,
                 phase4:5,
                 phase5:0
               },
          Robin:{
                 phase1:16,
                 phase2:12,
                 phase3:21,
                 phase4:23,
                 phase5:2               
                }
        }
```

Now I wanted to convert them to where `data` variable is object and `anna` and `robin` is array of objects:

```
data = {
          anna:[
                 { phase1: 23 },
                 { phase2: 24 },
                 { phase3: 0 },
                 { phase4: 5 },
                 { phase5: 0 }
               ],
          Robin:[
                 { phase1: 16 },
                 { phase2: 12 },
                 { phase3: 21 },
                 { phase4: 23 },
                 { phase5: 2  }            
                ]
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function convertToArray(obj) {
 var retVal = [];
 for (key in obj) { //iterates through the list of key-val pairs
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
     retVal.push({ key: obj[key]});
   } //pushes it to newly created array
 }
 return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A function like below might help you:

EDIT: edited the answer accommodating changes suggested by cafebabe1991.

```
function convertToArray(obj) {
 var retVal = [];

 for (var key in obj) { { //iterates through the list of key-val pairs
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
   retVal.push({ key: obj[key]});  //pushes it to newly created array
  }
 }
```

Comment: This is not the ideal way to loop through an object... use object.hasOwnProperty(key) so it does not iterate over the other properties.
For further details read here .... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/loop-through-javascript-object